# I want to push a specific commit without pulling

Tags: git

I've made 2 separate changes: 
Added feature 
Uploaded an image

The feature is not approved yet so I can't commit and push it yet.
But image is fine so I have to push it.

When I try to push it, it tells me to do the pull.
When I try to do the pull, it tells me that feature change that I've made will be removed unless I commit them.

It there a way just to push an image?

Thanks

Comment: you can stash your changes or you can create a new local branch, where you can commit your work without push it to the remote

Comment: Your question is confusing because you say that you want to push a specific commit, but you then say that you haven't committed yet, so there is no commit at all (much less a "specific" commit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image change is fine, then there is no reason not to commit and push it:

```
git add path/to/image
git commit -m 'made image change'
git push origin master
```

Assuming the remainder of the changes are for the feature, you could stash those changes:

```
git stash
```

Then, pull in the latest changes from the remote branch via:

```
git pull origin master
```

Finally, apply your stash:

```
git stash apply
```

Now your image change is on the server, and your working directory has the feature work.  If you get merge conflicts along the way, you will have to resolve them.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I didn't know about stashing, it helped:)

Comment: yes it did. I committed the image -> stashed the feature -> pulled/pushed -> applied stash. Thanks!